# Facebook ShareDialogs update rather than display individually

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to integrate the Facebook ShareDialog within my Android app. The actual sharing dialog works fine  app side but when viewing on a Facebook timeline shared link's do not show as individual posts but rather the initial first post simply updates the last and the title displays "Title posted xx updates." (I'm expecting "Title shared a link").

If I look at the Facebook activity log it shows all individual posts as shared links?

Is this a feature of the Facebook timeline or is there something i'm missing in my ShareDialog app side that will pst all links as individual links on timeline?

ShareDialog code:

```
if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
        final ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                .setContentTitle(titleText)
                .setContentDescription(descriptionText)
                .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://example.com"))
                .setImageUrl(Uri.parse(imageUrl))
                .build();
        ShareDialog shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);
        shareDialog.show(linkContent);

    }
```

Comment: Yes, grouping of posts is a thing Facebook does automatically, you can not influence it.

Comment: Yep, looks like its a combination of two things, I am posting and reviewing on the same Facebook account. Friends actually see the individual posts where FB group them on my own Feed. This and the general black box that is the FB feed algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is ultimately down to the Facebook feed algorithm and the fact I was posting and reviewing on the same device.
When I post and then review from a friends perspective, the friend Feed actually shows the individual post (if the FB algorithm thinks your friend would be interested in this post).

Answer (score 0):

[Facebook's policy](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill) states that it's **not** allowed to:

> Pre-fill the user message parameter with any content the user didn't
>   enter themselves, even if they can edit or delete that content before
>   sharing. This applies to posts, comments, photo captions, and photo
>   album captions.

The same is also stated at the [publish_actions permissions reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-publish_actions).

I guess they decided to block this.